# A Rational function with a common factor in numerator and the denominator

Tags: functions

We have recently started studying rational functions at school. I have learnt that a rational function is the ratio of two polynomials, i.e

$y$ = $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$

My question is, what if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have a common factor (linear, quadratic, etc) ??

For example, $y$ = $\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-2)(x-3)}$

Is it still a rational function? We haven’t studied calculus in maths yet, but we have studied a little bit of calculus in our physics classes, and from what I know, I can cancel out the common factor but the function is discontinuous at $x$ = $2$, i.e it has a hole.

So is it still a rational function?

Answer (score 2):

A *rational function* is defined to be any function $f(x)$ that can be expressed as 
$ \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)},$ where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials and $Q(x)$ is not the zero polynomial.

So, for example, a linear function such as $f(x) = x$ is a rational function (as all polynomials are) because you can express $f(x)$ as $f(x) = \frac{x}{1}$, a polynomial of degree 1 divided by a polynomial of degree 0.

Rational functions, of course, can have "holes" because they are continuous everywhere except where we would divide by zero; e.g., $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x-1}$ is a rational function whose graph looks like the graph of the constant function $y=1$ except there is a point missing at $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying it. So rational functions can have 'holes', that's what I was not very sure about. I googled it, it didn't help. So I posted it on here. Your explanation cleared it up, so thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Just curious. Can I say that the range of $y$ = $\frac{x-1}{x-1}$ is {$1$} ? I'm just confused because I know this rational function is similar to the constant function $y$ = $1$, but is undefined at $x$ = $1$, if it weren't undefined at $x$ = $1$, the y value of the rational function would have been $1$ at $x$ = $1$. So can I still say that its range is {$1$} ?

Comment: Yes; the range is the set of real $y$ values corresponding to the set of $x$-values in the domain. As every $x$-value in the domain  produces a $y$-value of $1$, the range is simply, $\lbrace  1 \rbrace$. (I'm glad that you showed the braces in your question as they are necessary. )

Comment: Thanks again :) Can't wait before we study functions. But until then, just wanted to clear my doubts